# How to synchronize different actions in Swift Language for IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I created a timer in one class, and tried to do something else in another class while timer works, and do other thing while timer stops. For example, show every second when timer works.  I simplified the code as below. How to realize that?

```
import Foundation
import UIView

class TimerCount {
var timer: NSTimer!
var time: Int!
init(){
    time = 5
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( 1.0 , target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func update(){
    if(time > 0) {
       time = time - 1
        // do something while timer works
    }
    else{
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        time = 5
    }
}
}


class Main: UIView {
var Clock: TimerCount!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    Clock = TimerCount()
    //? do something else while clock works
    // ? do other things while clock stops
    // FOR EXAMPLE: show every second when timer works
    if(Clock.time > 0){
        println(Clock.time)
    }else{
        println("clocker stops")
    }

}        
}
```

Comment: are you asking how to reference the variable `time` in class TimerCount from the class Main?

Comment: I know how to do that, and I add it in the sample code above to clarify the purpose. Do you know how to show every second in Main class, not in TimerCount class?

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is most likely only going to be called once. You could simply make the update method be in your `Main` object and then pass that instance of main and that update method into the `scheduledTimerWithTimerInterval` call. Otherwise you need a new method in the Main class to call from the timerCount class and pass in the int for the current time.

This is in your Main class:

```
func updateMethodInMain(timeAsInt: Int){
//do stuff in Main instance based on timeAsInt
}
```

This is what you have in your timer class:

```
func update(){
    if(time > 0) {
       time = time - 1
        instanceNameForMain.updateMethodInMain(time)
    }
    else{
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        time = 5
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I know your method, but in my specific condition, it is not allowed. As I asked,I would like  to solve this only in main class, without changing or modify TimerCount class. In other words, I want to know whether swift has a method to register or monitor the timer activity?

Comment: I suggest the first option which would allow you to only modify main. Though the second option would be the standard.